# How to animate slide left smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following

```
        $('.left_arrow').hover(function() {
            $('.chart').stop().animate({
                left: "+=10"
            });
        },
        function() {
            $('.chart').stop();
        });
```

And I want to have it when you mouse over the arrow it smoothly moves the `.chart` to the left, and the right arrow it moves it to the right. I am doing this by applying a `- left (-7500px is the max)` to move it to the left and a `0` is the farthest it can go right.

The above moves it over 10, but it doesn't keep on moving it. How can I get it so it keeps on moving it. I was using something like

```
        $('.left_arrow').hover(function() {
            $('.chart').stop().animate({
                left: "-7500px"
            }, 20000);
        },
        function() {
            $('.chart').stop();
        });
```

But the problem is if I am say `-6500px` over it takes 20 seconds to go the rest of the 1000, vs 20 seconds to go the full distance. So the speed is skewed, I want a standard increment.

Comment: Difficult to fully understanding without some working code, but the default easing for `.animate()` is `swing`. If you want a "standard increment" - change the easing type to `linear`

Comment: I want to mouse over an arrow, and have a div move left by using a negative left css property, but I want it to be increment, rather then based on the remaining distance.

Comment: I'll provide an aswer, one sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is a rate function. I had the same issue when I was creating my carousel.

```
rate = distance/time
```

So, your rate is `0.375`

Now, all you will need to do is find the distance and you can adjust your timing accordingly.

```
time = distance/0.375
```

So it should look something like this:

```
    $('.left_arrow').hover(function() {
        var distance = /*Get Distance Remaining*/
        var sd = 7500;
        var time = 20000;
        var rate = sd/time;
        var time = distance/rate

        $('.chart').stop().animate({
            left: "-7500px"
        }, time);
    },
    function() {
        $('.chart').stop();
    });
```

Obviously it would need some tweaking to get just right. But the concept is there.

For my situation, because I was using a `<ul>` since it was a carousel this is the way I got distance:

```
distance = Math.abs($ul.position().left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding the question, but you can increment/decrement animations like so:

```
$('.chart').stop().animate({
    "left": "+=100px"
}, 250);
```

Note the `+=` operator.

**EDIT**: This answer is only partially correct. Animation behavior on hover is not as desired. Trying to solve.

Comment: I tried that, but it moves by 100px's and then stops. How do I get it to keep going?

Comment: Well, it's nested in a `hover`, so it will only executing while you're hovering. Also, try removing `.stop()` method and executing it elsewhere/once